# iterating over container of objects from an inheritance hierarchy while hiding pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, containers, dynamic-binding

The issue I am having is the following: I have an inheritance hierarchy of objects, and I want to define a class that represents a collection of objects from this hierarchy that can have different dynamic types. I am wondering if there is a way to make and iterate over such a collection while hiding the fact that it contains pointers. Currently my code can be summarized as follows :

```
class Base{
    public:
       virtual Base* clone() const & { return new Base(*this); }
       virtual Base* clone() && { return new Base( std::move(*this) ); }
    ... other members ...

};

class Derived : public Base{
    public: 
        Derived* clone() const & override { return new Derived(*this); }
        Derived* clone() && override { return new Derived( std::move(*this) ); }
    ... other members ...
};

class ObjectCollection{
    public:
        ... constructor and other members...

        // use 'clone' function to initialize the collection without having to pass pointers
        void push_back( const Base& );
        void push_back( Base&& );

        using iterator = std::vector< std::shared_ptr< Base > >::iterator
        using const_iterator = std::vector< std::shared_ptr< Base > >::const_iterator

        iterator begin(){ return collection.begin(); }
        const_iterator begin() const{ return collection.cbegin(); }

        iterator end() { return collection.end(); }
        const_iterator end() const{ return collection.cend(); }
    private: 
        std::vector< std::shared_ptr< Base > > collection;
};

//loop over objects:
ObjectCollection collection(...call to constructor...);
for( auto & object : collection ){
    //object is now a reference to shared_ptr to Object rather than a reference to Object!
}
```

Ideally I would like to be able to write a for loop like the last one, where I can get references to the objects directly rather than pointers. Is there a way to achieve this? Or would it be better to keep working with pointers? (Note: one way I know of to solve the problem, but which I would like to avoid, is to overload the [] operator to already dereference the pointers).

Comment: Roll your own iterator that wraps the underlying one, but dereferences for you.

Answer (score 0):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you might create reference view of your `shared_ptr` collection:

```
auto get_collection_view() /*const*/
{
    return collection | ranges::v3::transform([](auto&& p) -> /*const*/ Base& { return *p; });
}
```